# Does an ADODB Recordset generate SQL upon update?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, adodb

When you load a record in the recordset, change some data and call Update, what is update doing?

I understand that Recordset uses a DB cursor, so it's possible that no "update" sql statements are used to update, but rather some sort of direct update?

Comment: Fire up SQL Server Profiler and have a look at what is executed on the server. For disconnected recordsets it builds the update statements necessary when you call `UpdateBatch`. I don't know how connected works using update/post. Might be a difference between server side / client side cursor.s Might also be different depending on concurrency setting.

Comment: Note. In the end there **always is** an update/delete/insert executed. The code generated might look different depending on ....( see above)

Comment: This was my assumption too, there always is an update/delete/insert executed. But Adodb is unique in interface, and it wouldn't surprise me if there was some voodoo. I used to use it years ago, and it's only looking back at an old project with my recent experiences with EF that I wonder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed some tests and found that ADODB does in fact still run SQL Update statements. No voodoo as feared.